# Why does Snowflake NUMBER(20,0) export to CSV with decimals?

Tags: csv, types, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, export

I have a Snowflake table with a `NUMBER(20,0)` column. When I export it to CSV, I get values like `32780431.1`, but I expected integers.

```
>describe view LEADS_FOR_FARADAY;
+------------+--------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+---------+-------------+
| name       | type         | kind   | null? | default | primary key | unique key | check | expression | comment | policy name |
|------------+--------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+---------+-------------|
| LEAD_ID    | NUMBER(20,0) | COLUMN | Y     | NULL    | N           | N          | NULL  | NULL       | NULL    | NULL        |
```

Here is the export SQL:

```
COPY INTO 's3://mybucket/asdasd/'
FROM (
  SELECT
    "LEAD_ID"
  FROM
    LEADS_FOR_FARADAY
  WHERE
    true
)
HEADER = true
FILE_FORMAT = (
  TYPE = CSV
  FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"'
  ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD=NONE
)
```

Here is the proof:

```
$ xsv select LEAD_ID 20240108-40-2r45u4.csv 
37952160.1
37237141.1
35179659.1
39258186.1
33452333.1
```

If I cast 1.1 to `NUMBER(20,0)`, Snowflake gives me 1:

[image: Showing how cast gives me 1]

What is going on?

*** UPDATE ***

It turns out it is a view with an underlying table:

```
select get_ddl('table', 'LEADS_FOR_FARADAY');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+               
| GET_DDL('TABLE', 'LEADS_FOR_FARADAY')                         |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| create or replace view LEADS_FOR_FARADAY(                     |
|   LEAD_ID,                                                    |
| ) as                                                          |
| SELECT * FROM DATA_MARTS.OTHER_SCHEMA.LEADS_FOR_FARADAY;      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

That table has `LEAD_ID` as a float:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE DATA_MARTS.OTHER_SCHEMA.LEADS_FOR_FARADAY;
+--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+---------+-------------+
| name               | type              | kind   | null? | default | primary key | unique key | check | expression | comment | policy name |
|--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+---------+-------------|
| LEAD_ID            | FLOAT             | COLUMN | Y     | NULL    | N           | N          | NULL  | NULL       | NULL    | NULL
```

Yet the view considers it a NUMBER(20,0):

```
DESCRIBE TABLE LEADS_FOR_FARADAY;
+--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+---------+-------------+
| name               | type              | kind   | null? | default | primary key | unique key | check | expression | comment | policy name |
|--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+---------+-------------|
| LEAD_ID            | NUMBER(20,0)      | COLUMN | Y     | NULL    | N           | N          | NULL  | NULL       | NULL    | NULL        |
```

Maybe this view was made before the underlying table was changed?

Comment: Can you provide the DDL for that view?  Also, is it possible that you have a table using the same name?